# Interface Builder UIView background turns black after segue

Tags: uiview, interface-builder, segue

I have a UIView laid out in IB on a storyboard with a modal transition type.  It has transparent sections that should show parts of the underlying UIView after the segue.  I can see that those areas are transparent during the animation, but once the movement is complete, they turn black.

I have tried `[self.view setOpaque:NO]` and `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]` in the following locations and it doesn't seem to work.

In first view

- prepareForSegue

In a custom segue class

- perform

In modal view

- initWithNibName
- viewDidLoad
- viewWillAppear

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the view being covered up goes away after the animation leaving a black background. Set a breakpoint in the underlying view in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear and see if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is unloading or at least not redrawing the view beneath.

Perhaps you could just  slide a view in from the bottom, rather than modally presenting a new view controller?

Another solution is to prepare an image of the view underneath and set it as the background.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation. And found after sent `presentModalViewController:animated:` message to source view controller, the source view will be set to disappear. I think that's why we got a black background.